# How to use AsynchronousSocketChannel with CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, sockets, asynchronous

I need to read some amount of bytes from `AsynchronousSocketChannel`, process them and read bytes again. During the second reading I get a `java.nio.channels.ReadPendingException`.
Is it possible to avoid this exception without using blocking methods like `Future.get()`?

In the example, `readOneByte()` and `readTwoBytes()` read bytes and process them. Should this function also return an instance of `CompletableFuture`? How to avoid callback chaos then?

```
byte[] bytes = { 0x00 };
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> writeBytes(bytes, channel))
                .thenRun(() -> readOneByte(channel))
                .thenApply(f -> readTwoBytes(channel)) // here is ReadPendingException
                .thenAccept(bytes -> doSmthWithBytes(bytes))
```

Comment: Issue the next read in the completion handler for the current read.